# RowUpdating Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datagridview, aspxgridview, cgridview

---

```
protected void GridView2_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{

    DB_Function.OpenConniction();

    string ExpID = GridView2.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();

    string CompNm = ((TextBox)GridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Controls[0]).Text;
    string JobTitel = ((TextBox)GridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Controls[0]).Text;

    string WorkPlace = ((TextBox)GridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Controls[0]).Text;
    string StartDate = ((TextBox)GridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Controls[0]).Text;

    string EndDate = ((TextBox)GridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Controls[0]).Text;
    string ReasonLeave = ((TextBox)GridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[6].Controls[0]).Text;

    string CompPhone = ((TextBox)GridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[7].Controls[0]).Text;


    if(DB_Function.UpdateExperiance(ExpID)>0)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;

        lblState.Text = " Row is Updated ";
        lblState.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;

    }
}
```

---

```
public static int UpdateExperiance(string ExpID , string CompNm , string JobTitel , string WorkPlace , string StartDate , string EndDate , string ReasonLeave , string CompPhone)
{
    string Strcon = @"Data Source=MAHMOD-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Task;Integrated Security=True";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Strcon);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "SP_U_Experiances";

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExpID", ExpID);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompNm", CompNm);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JobTitel", JobTitel);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WorkPlace", WorkPlace);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", StartDate);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDate", EndDate);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReasonLeave", ReasonLeave);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompPhone", CompPhone);

    con.Open();
    return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: what do you want? please format question properly

Comment: Are you having problems getting the changed values?  Do you know you can do this:

GridViewRow row = GridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex];

string CompNm = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[1].Controls[0])).Text;  

It's much easier to read.

Comment: i have Problem in GridView >> Row Updating

Comment: Please Anyones Help me in this Erorr

Answer (score -1):

You aren't rebinding your data after you do the database update.

```
protected void GridView2_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{

    DB_Function.OpenConniction();

string ExpID = GridView2.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();

string CompNm = ((TextBox)GridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Controls[0]).Text;
string JobTitel = ((TextBox)GridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Controls[0]).Text;

string WorkPlace = ((TextBox)GridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Controls[0]).Text;
string StartDate = ((TextBox)GridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Controls[0]).Text;

string EndDate = ((TextBox)GridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Controls[0]).Text;
string ReasonLeave = ((TextBox)GridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[6].Controls[0]).Text;

string CompPhone = ((TextBox)GridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[7].Controls[0]).Text;


    if(DB_Function.UpdateExperiance(ExpID)>0)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;

        lblState.Text = " Row is Updated ";
        lblState.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;

        BindData();
    }
}
```

Where BindData is where you retrieve your data:

```
private void BindData()
{
    GridView2.DataSource = (your data source);
    GridView2.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: i have method Fill_Experiance()